# Design of 5+ channel microphone array

Tags: microcontroller, microphone, antenna-array

I'm interested in designing a microphone array which will have 5+ inputs which need to be synced, possibly more. I want to sample each input at 20-30khz at 8-10 bit resolution.

I would prefer not have to have 5 separate ADC but the MEMS microphones I have seen which include ADC all use an odd protocol which I am not sure about.

Additionally even if the microphones all used SPI or I2C out I don't think I have seen any microcontroller which has 5+ inputs.

What would be the standard approach to this problem?

Comment: [This application note](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00380469-interfacing-pdm-digital-microphones-using-stm32-mcus-and-mpus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) by ST might help, they display a configuration for up to 8 microphones with PDM (is that your odd protocol?) output. I haven't done anything in the field, so can't comment if that approach is good or whatever.

Comment: @FourierFlux:  For SPI, you only need one SPI channel, and a handful of outputs.  One output for each ADC to drive the slave select pin.  Select one ADC, read value over SPI.  Select next ADC, read value over SPI, repeat.

Comment: You can also use Quad SPI with multiple ADCs, the internal data handling might get a bit odd depending on how the peripheral assigns the bits though...

Comment: The problem is the streams need to be synchronized so multiplexing isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

The standard protocol for microphone arrray using digital MEMS would be [PDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-density_modulation). It can be directly interfaced with some microcontrollers and microprocessors/SoCs at up to 8 channels.

One option is to use an STM32 microcontroller. This is described in
[AN5027: Connecting PDM digital microphones to STM32 MCUs and MPUs](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00380469-interfacing-pdm-digital-microphones-using-stm32-mcus-and-mpus-stmicroelectronics.pdf).
Other microcontroller options would be [NXP imx rt600](https://no.mouser.com/new/nxp-semiconductors/nxp-i-mx-rt600-mcus/)

Another options would be SoC like RockChip RK3588 (or similar) with Embedded Linux.

The most plug-and-play would be to use a multi-channel PDM to USB soundcard.
[MiniDSP UMA-16](https://www.minidsp.com/products/usb-audio-interface/uma-16-microphone-array) would be one option. They also have some documentation on how to do custom array geometries and processing.
[UMA array with MATLAB](https://www.minidsp.com/applications/usb-mic-array/uma-8-16-matlab).